# Cost of toString() in logging

Tags: java, log4j, tostring

```
Class MyComplexClass{
   // No override of toString() here
   }
   …

  log.debug(“Something happened here{}”, myObject.toString())
```

Other than the redundancy of the toString() here, is it possible if the log level is changed, the cost of toString() is still incurred?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the logging framework; but any "sensible" framework won't invoke `toString()` if it's not going to write anything to the log.

Comment: @AndyTurner but only if `toString()` is not explicitly called. The statement should be `log.debug(“Something happened here{}”, myObject)`. Several logging frameworks also have lazy evaluation using suppliers.

Comment: @RobSpoor sorry, I thought it was implicit that it will be invoked if you explicitly invoke it. I'm talking about if you don't explicitly invoke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the cost is still incurred.

No matter which log level is used, the code always calls `myObject.toString()` before log.debug is called.

This:

```
log.debug("Something happened here {}", myObject.toString());
```

is *exactly the same* as this:

```
String s = myObject.toString();
log.debug("Something happened here {}", s);
```

As you can see, the toString() call happens every single time.  It is not under the control of the logger at all.

The way to be sure the cost of toString is only incurred when the corresponding log level is active is to avoid calling toString, and let the logger library’s own code call toString if and only if such a call is needed:

```
// Notice there is no visible toString call!
log.debug("Something happened here {}", myObject);
```